# Dynamic load Image Target in Vuforia is possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, vuforia

I am new in ios Vuforia development.In the given examples of vuforia, we have all the image targets placed. But for the application we develop, there will be large amount of photos and it will keep on changing ,So is there any way to load Image Target itself from a database using Web Service ?
Any suggestions on how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0):

just download that file from network, store it within application directories and load it like the sample data bundled with the app

```
 NSString * pathToDownloadedFile; //should have path to your file

 QCAR::DataSet *dataSet = nil;
 QCAR::TrackerManager& trackerManager = QCAR::TrackerManager::getInstance();
 QCAR::ImageTracker* imageTracker = static_cast<QCAR::ImageTracker*>              (trackerManager.getTracker(QCAR::Tracker::IMAGE_TRACKER));
 dataSet = imageTracker->createDataSet();
 dataSet->load([pathToDownloadedFile cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], QCAR::DataSet::STORAGE_ABSOLUTE);


 imageTracker->activateDataSet(dataSet);
```

Comment: how can i download .xml and .dat file programatically  why because my target images changing  dynamically ?